# How do I connect to a locally run http server?

Tags: lan

At home I'm using an ASUS RT-N66R router. I'm connected to it over WiFi.

My laptop has an IP address of 192.168.1.86. I'm running an HTTP server on port 8000.

Why can't I connect to the server by going to http://192.168.1.86:8000/, but I can connect to it by going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ ?

Comment: You are running a firewall?

Comment: I am. But isn't the firewall just protecting my external IP address?

Comment: Not if you are running it on the local computer as opposed to your router.

Comment: if a firewall is on a computer itself i'm not sure that it'd even deal with your external address at all, it'd certainly control access regarding your internal addresses.   Also check what IP the server is bound to e.g.  `netstat -aon` at cmd. See if it says 0.0.0.0 or 192.168.1.86 or 127.0.0.1  before the `:8000` 'cos if it is bound to 127.0.0.1 then that would be the first cause of you only being able to connect from 127.0.0.1  If it's boudn to an 192 address it means it will allow your whole internal network,and if it's bound to 0.0.0.0 it'll allow any. After that a firewall might restrict.

Comment: Yeah, I ran the server at 192.168.1.86 and I'm able to connect to it. Thanks.